# python.exe is getting crashed at time of frame close

Tags: python

I am making an application using wxpython in which i have imported some modules and added the some widgets but when i am closing the application window ie Frame(wxFrame) python.exe getting crashed and showing the following message "python.exe get  encountered a problem and need to be close... Tell microsoft donttell smt smt".

My app is working fine but this msg is coming while closing the app there is no message coming why its occur.
Should i do something like deleting the wxwindows or bitmap of wxpython (i think some handle or some obj of wxpython/python like dict or list are in memory so manually i shd delete that, its my perception only may be wrong or right) if i am right then what thing of wxpython shd be deleted manually so this message shd not be appear.

Any help really appreciable.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start debugging it, and see where it crashes. If you are not familiar with [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) or such debugger try print statements to pinpoint the location where it crashes, once you are sure what code crashes may be we can help then.